# Automated copy of records only (no metadata) from Production to Sandbox

Tags: metadata, sandbox

I have read and researched on google and find that any refresh, clone or copy options copies all or selected data plus the metadata or only the metadata from the Production org to Sandbox. Is there a way to copy just the records or data and no metadata from Production to Sandbox without a third-party tool? And can this process be automated?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SFDX for this. I am not sure what level of experience you have with it but the guide over here walks you through an example of how that can be done.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data_example.htm

A trailhead to get started with SFDX - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx/set-up-your-salesforce-dx-environment

Also not sure what you mean by automating this process but you can run a script that essentially runs these commands and loads the data into any Sandbox.

Comment: Thank you, Nitin. I am very new to Salesforce. I will check out the link you have sent. What I meant by automation was if there is a way to set up an automatic monthly copy of all records from Production into the Full Copy Sandbox without changing the metadata in the Sandbox

Comment: Thanks for clarification Jasmine! May I know what you're trying to achieve here? As long as you do not make any metadata changes in your production org you can refresh the Full Copy Sandbox every 29 days which and copy the data. Sandboxes in salesforce exist to make customizations and act as pre-prod environments for you experiment with stuff. A good overview on how to use sandboxes => [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B73qPE1pEj4&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=SalesforceSupport). Let me know if this helps or if I got you completely wrong :)